# That's a prime... almost

Tags: code-golf, math, number, number-theory, primes

If you've ever learned about primes in math class, you've probably have had to, at one point, determine if a number is prime. You've probably messed up while you were still learning them, for example, mistaking 39 for a prime. Well, not to worry, as 39 is a semiprime, i.e., that it is the product of two primes.

Similarly, we can define a *k*-almost prime as being the product of *k* prime numbers. For example, 40 is the 4th 4-almost prime; 40 = 5*2*2*2, the product of 4 factors.

Your task is to write a program/function that accepts two integers *n* and *k* as input and output/return the *n*th *k*-almost prime number. This is a code-golf, so the shortest program in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
n, k => output
n, 1 => the nth prime number
1, 1 => 2
3, 1 => 5
1, 2 => 4
3, 2 => 9
5, 3 => 27
```

## Miscellaneous

You have to generate the primes yourself by any means other than a simple closed form, if such a closed form exists.

Comment: Check your math in your first example: 40 is not equal to 5*2*2*2*2.

Comment: @GamrCorps Ah, yes, thank you.

Comment: How do you define the *nth* k-almost prime? What determines what order the k-almost primes are in?

Comment: @GamrCorps Similar to how you determine the *n*th prime: you can generate a list of the first *n* numbers with *k* prime factors, sorted from least to greatest, and take the last member in that list.

Comment: I don't think your expression for `f` in terms of `f[n,1]` is correct, since the lists of almost-primes contain odd numbers (e.g. the last two examples, which are not expressible as the product of a power of two and a prime).  (And it also says that `f[n,1] == 2*f[n,1]`.)

Comment: @2012rcampion Oh, my mistake. It was a simple observation that was not founded by proof.

Comment: Why is a simple closed form banned?

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn't make sense. There's no known closed form for the problem you are asking, and in fact there are proofs that such a closed form does *not* exists (when taking operations from certain sets of operations [e.g. surely no polynomial exists that produces all primes ]).

Comment: @Bakuriu I don't know much about the proofs. I was merely trying to ban trivial solutions.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there **aren't** trivial solutions. Just say that it must work with `1 <= n <= 100` and `1 <= k <= 10`, so that storing the solutions in a table is infeasible and you are done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Pyth, 9 bytes

```
e.fqlPZQE
```

Explanation

```
          - autoassign Q = eval(input())
     PZ   -      prime_factors(Z) 
    l     -     len(^)
   q   Q  -    ^ == Q
 .f     E -  first eval(input()) of (^ for Z in range(inf))
e         - ^[-1]
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.fqlPZQE&input=3%0A5&debug=0)

[Or try a test suite!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.fqlPZQE&input=3%0A5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A1%0A1%0A3%0A2%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A3%0A5&debug=0&input_size=2)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

Beating @sundar by using half as much bytes

```
{~l~ḋ}ᶠ⁽t
```

## Explanation

```
                    --  Input like [n,k]
{    }ᶠ⁽            --      Find the first n values which
   ~ḋ               --          have a prime decomposition
 ~l                 --          of length k
        t           --      and take the last one
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7oup@7hju7ah9sWPGrcW/L/f7SpjnHs/ygA)

Answer (score 5):

## Jelly, 9 bytes

```
ÆfL=³
ç#Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZmTD3CswrDhyPhuao&input=&args=Mw+NQ)

#### How it works

```
Ç#Ṫ    Main link. Left input: k. Right input: n.

Ç      Apply the helper link to k, k + 1, k + 2, ... until...
 #       n matches are found.
  Ṫ    Retrieve the last match.


ÆfL=³  Helper link. Left argument: k (iterator)

Æf     Yield the prime factors of k.
  L    Compute the length of the list, i.e., the number of prime factors.
   =³  Compare the result with k (left input).
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any encoding that can save these 9 characters as 9 bytes.

Comment: Jelly uses a [custom encoding](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md) that represents the 256 character it understands with single bytes.

Answer (score 4):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/tree/9e0140f09cee5922e3931615c31216eb387738ce) (commit 29), 8 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
.fPlQq)e
```

Explanation:

```
         - autoassign Q = eval_or_not(input())
.f    )  - First eval_or_not(input) of (^ for i in range(inf))
  P      -    prime_factors(i)
   l     -   len(^)
     q   -  ^==V
    Q    -   Q
       e - ^[-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>84</s> <s>78</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```
f(n,k,i=1)=n>0?f(n-(sum(values(factor(i)))==k),k,i+1):i-1
```

This is a recursive function that accepts two integers and returns an integer. The approach here is to check the sum of the exponents in the prime factorization against `k`.

Ungolfed:

```
function f(n, k, i=1)
    # We initialize a counter i as a function argument.

    # Recurse while we've encountered fewer than n k-almost primes
    if n > 0
        # If the sum of the exponents in the prime factorization of i is
        # equal to k, there are k prime factors of i. We subtract a boolean
        # from n, which is implicitly cast to an integer, which will
        # decrement n if i is k-almost prime and leave it as is otherwise.
        return f(n - (sum(values(factor(i))) == k), k, i + 1)
    else
        # Otherwise we return i-1 (i will have been incremented one too
        # many times, hence the -1)
        return i - 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
λǐL⁰=;ȯt
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLOu8eQTOKBsD07yK90IiwiIiwiNVxuMyJd)

```
λ    ;ȯt # Nth number where
 ǐL      # Prime factor length
   ⁰=    # Equal to input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
,1{hH&t<NḋlH;N}ⁱ⁽t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X8ewOsNDrcTG7@GO7hwPa7/aR40bHzXuLfn/P9pUR8E49n8UAA)

```
                      Implicit input, say [5, 3]
,1                    Append 1 to the input list. [5, 3, 1]
  {           }ⁱ⁽     Repeat this predicate the number of times given by
                        the first element of the list (5),
                        on the rest of the list [3, 1]
   hH&                Let's call the first element H
      t<N             There is a number N greater than the second element
         ḋ            Whose prime factorization's
          l           length
           H          is equal to H
            ;N        Then, pair that N with H and let that be input for
                      the next iteration
                 t    At the end of iterations, take the last N
                      This is implicitly the output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Sidef](https://github.com/trizen/sidef), 21 bytes

```
nth_almost_prime(n,k)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>56</s> 51 bytes

```
Last@Select[Range[2^##],PrimeOmega@#==n&/.n->#2,#]&
```

Warning: This is theoretical. Do not run for any values>4. Replace 2^## with a more efficient expression.

Comment: This doesn't work for `n=1`.

Comment: Also since `PrimeOmega[1]` evaluates to `0`, `&&#>1` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>53</s> 49 Bytes

```
Cases[Range[2^(#2+#)],x_/;PrimeOmega@x==#2][[#]]&
```

Generates a list of integers based on a loose upper bound. `PrimeOmega` counts the prime factors with multiplicities, the *k*-almost prime `Cases` are taken from the list, and the *n*th member of that subset is returned.

Comment: 2^(0+##), or just 2^## works.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Try `2^Sequence[1,2]` to see why the latter fails.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 88 bytes

Can probably be golfed a lot more, as I'm still a newbie to Haskell. The function `q` returns the number of factors of its argument, and `f` uses that to get take the `nth` element of a list made from all numbers that have `k` factors.

```
q n|n<2=0|1>0=1+q(div n ([x|x<-[2..],mod n x<1]!!0))
f n k=filter(\m->q m==k)[1..]!!n-1
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 14 bytes

```
:YqiZ^!XpSu1G)
```

[Try it on MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%3AYqiZ%5E%21XpSu1G%29&inputs=5%0A3&version=20.9.2)

```
:               % Take first input n implicitly, make range 1 to n
 Yq             % Get corresponding prime numbers (1st prime to nth prime)
   i            % Take the second input k
    Z^          % Take the k-th cartesian power of the primes list 
                % (Getting all combinations of k primes)
      !Xp       % Multiply each combination (2*2*2, 2*2*3, 2*2*5, ...)
         Su     % Sort and unique
           1G)  % Take the n-th element of the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 100 bytes

This is a very simple brute force function. It checks every number starting from 2 with `sympy`'s `factorint` function until it has found `n` `k`-almost primes, at which point, the function returns the `n`th of these.

```
import sympy
def a(n,k):
 z=1;c=0
 while c<n:z+=1;c+=(sum(sympy.factorint(z).values())==k)
 return z
```

**Ungolfed:**

I use `sum(factorint(a).values())` because `factorint` returns a dictionary of `factor: exponent` pairs. Grabbing the values of the dictionary (the exponents) and summing them tells me how many prime factors there are and thus what `k` this `k`-almost prime is.

```
from sympy import factorint
def almost(n, k):
    z = 1
    count = 0
    while count < n: 
        z += 1
        if sum(factorint(a).values()) == k:
            count += 1
    return z
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 76 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k,p=2,c=0:c==k if p>n else f(n,k,p+1,c)if n%p else f(n/p,k,p,c+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xDgIhEEVrOcU0JpCdRNhYbYIXMRaIjBLW2Qlu4@lxsTC2772fL@/1sfDYGvk5PK@3AIwFxY8YvZ2i9wUygZwY0vxKQPqrB4fRbJz38uMH6Qbj4EyjpcI2ZKiB70k7PJpJ7aRmXqHgOUMP8l9grek/pDMWc1GqfQA)